# When you ask about some photos : "Did you take these?"/"Did you take them?"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, questions

If I ask about some photos that my friend has, 
I could ask "Did you take these photos?". But I wonder if these two forms could be used too or only one of them is correct to use.

"Did you take these?"/"Did you take them?"

- I edited the 'took' to 'take' :-) Thanks!

Comment: "Did you took" is wrong. You can say "Did you take these?" (indicating a particular group of photos) or "Did you take them?" if your friend already knows which ones you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you!!  I edited the question accordingly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did you take these?

Implies you are in possession of the photos, or that they are close by, and you are referencing them physically/pointing them out.

> Did you take those?

Implies they are in the possession of the other person, or not close by, and you are referencing them physically/pointing them out.

> Did you take them?

A more general way to refer to the photos, as a concept/idea only, without reference to proximity/possession. Perhaps the photos are not present, or they are already a known part of the conversation; you are discussing them without referencing them as being physically present in some way.